# time complexity of loops

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, functional-programming, c++, code-generation

what is the time complexity of:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i = 2*i)
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            sum++;
```

?
I thought it is O(nlogn) since the otter loop run logn time and the inner loop run i time

Comment: This site doesn't work that way. Help us to help you: why do you doubt your answer? what don't you understand? We're not a verifier service.

Comment: My question is what is the complexity of the provided code ?

Comment: Always helpful when you don’t have experience yet: Write a program that counts your operations and prints them. Check the output, make a guess check the guess. You’ll see it’s unlikely to be n log n.

Answer (score 2):

Conside [Geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)

$1+2+4+8+...+n=2n-1$.

So time complexity is $O(n)$.